# java 8 stream groupBy and new object creation

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

Let's say I have two classes C1 and C2 where C2 is used by the constructor of C1:

```
public class C1
{
    public C1( C2 o2 ){ ... }

    public String getProperty()
    {
        String result;
        ...
        return result;
    }
}
```

Now, I have a list of C2 objects (List list) that I would like to stream and filter using a condition on the getProperty() of C1 created from the C2 objects that are streamed.

Is there a way to do this with a stream?

```
List<C2> list = ...
List<C2> result = list.stream().filter( XXXX )
```

where I guess I should have XXXX that creates a C1 object using a C2 object from the stream and compares its getProperty() (e.g., "value".equals (o2.getProperty())

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You'll be throwing away the instances, but sure

```
list.stream().filter(c2 -> "value".equals(new C1(c2).getProperty())).collect(toList());
```

---

This does seem kind of backwards. Perhaps the logic for this property should go in the `C2` class or some utility class (static method) or instance that provides the property for a given `C2` instance.

Comment: For whatever reason I was not able to use your solution as-is and I had to tweak the filter clause as follows: .filter( c2 -> {return "value".equals(new C1( c2 ).getProperty() ) ; } )

Comment: @david The `filter` invocation in your comment and the one in my question are 100% equivalent. There must be something that you aren't showing us. _For whatever reason_ It's not a _whatever reason_. If there's an error, the compiler would have told you.